# Stripping rails down for api use only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I have an app that we are using just to serve api calls to another application. However it feels heavy as it is still using the whole of rails, but we don't use views etc...

How has other people tackled this issue, just remove the files ? All I need left is my modules and the ability to serve.

Would it be better to use Sinatra ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the relatively new [rails-api](https://github.com/spastorino/rails-api) plugin, which offers a subset of Rails intended for building API services. You can read the release blog post [here](http://blog.wyeworks.com/2012/4/20/rails-for-api-applications-rails-api-released).

There's also a [Railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/348-the-rails-api-gem) demonstrating its use.

Comment: +1. We use a restful rails-api app as backend for several other apps, works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

At my job we're doing exactly what you need. Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with the process of making it work, somebody else set it up. What I know is that in config/application.rb you can select the things you need for your app. You can even add/delete middleware if you need to. In case it helps in our case we are using these frameworks:

```
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
```

And removing these middlewares:

```
config.middleware.delete Rack::Lock
config.middleware.delete ActionDispatch::Flash
config.middleware.delete ActionDispatch::Cookies
config.middleware.delete ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
config.middleware.delete ActionDispatch::BestStandardsSupport
```

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look at [GRAPE](https://github.com/intridea/grape) which does exactly this - it's a little like Sinatra (uses Rack) but very lightweight and API focused. [Webmachine](https://github.com/seancribbs/webmachine-ruby) is also pretty interesting (see http://code.dblock.org/grape-vs-webmachine for some comparisons)